# PHP fatal error: Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I am trying to make a comment page with this code but end up getting an error.

Here is the code:

```
 $query = ("SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY id DESC");

    $getquery = $connection->query($query);

    while($rows = ($getquery))
    {

        $id = $rows['id'];
        $names = $rows['name'];
        $comment = $rows['comment'];

        echo $name . '<br/>' . $comment . '<br/>' . '<br/>' ;
    }
```

And here is the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array in E:\utsdata\2T\2107982859\comment.php:61

Where line 61 is: `$id = $rows['id'];`

Comment: Line 61 -> $id = $rows['id'];

Comment: `foreach` instead of `while`.

Comment: You need to `fetch` rows: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Change

```
$getquery = $connection->query($query);
```

To

```
$getquery = $connection->prepare($query);
```

2) Change

```
 while($rows = ($getquery))
```

To

```
while ($rows = $getquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
```

3) Add `$getquery->execute();`

**Updated Code**

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY id DESC");

$getquery = $connection->prepare($query);
$getquery->execute();
while($result = $getquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);)
{

    $id = $rows['id'];
    $names = $rows['name'];
    $comment = $rows['comment'];

    echo $name . '<br/>' . $comment . '<br/>' . '<br/>' ;
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP make these changes? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: It's also broken now. The query is just prepared then, but never executed. So won't return any rows. (Besides the silly insistence on `->fetch` instead of utilizing the PDO iterator.)

Comment: I Updated my code. Please see @mario.